# sharedpreferences - getInt when button is clicked

Tags: android, onclick, sharedpreferences

**scenario** during a simple ball game i click exit and return to the menu and then exit out of the app,once i launch the app again I can click 'Continue" from the main menu and return to the game where i had left off or click New game and start again.

My problem is get sharedprefs are on onCreate, so even if i click 'New game' it continues from where i had left off.

I tried various onclick, findviewbyid methods and none of them worked, for example.

```
public class GActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private int RWIDTH = 70;
// + a whole bunch of other unrelated stuff that i cut-out to make viewing easier. 

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button CntButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConGame);
     CntButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            RWIDTH = settings.getInt("RWIDTH", RWIDTH);

        }
      });


 }

 protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

       editor.putInt("RWIDTH", RWIDTH);

   editor.commit();


  }
```

Comment: when&where are you committing RWIDTH variable?

Comment: Show us how you're saving the RWIDTH on your settings.

Comment: thats done before onCreate, "private int RWIDTH = 70;"

Comment: No. That's now what we meant. If you want to read it from the preferences you have to save it first. Where are you doing that?

Comment: oh, sorry added in edit - fixed

Comment: ya, when i click Continue from main menu, it reads from the preferences i have saved and continues from where i had left off, when i click new game, it begins a new game.

Comment: Are you sure your onStop is getting called and that you're saving? Try putting a breakpoint and debug.

Comment: yep that works fine, it saves - the code works when i leave the onclick method out but i only want it to work when i click 'continue' otherwise it would read it regardless of what button is pressed on onCreate.